# Нужно что бы при наведении на tr появлялся изначально скрытый td

Tags: jquery

```html
<tr class="d-flex">
                  <td>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <label for="" class="form-check-label">
                          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                        </label>
                      </div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="table__task__text">
                    <span class="notebookLine1 "></span>
                    <span class="notebookLine2 "></span>
                    <span class="tdLine"></span>
                      Buy a milk
                  </td>
                  <td class="ml-auto" id="vis">
                      <img src="images/movearrow.png
                      " alt="movearrow">
                      <span class="utilites__lines1"></span>
                      <img src="images/pencil.png" alt="chengetext" >
                      <span class="utilites__lines2"></span>
                      <img src="images/trashbox.png" alt="deletetask">
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="d-flex">
                  <td>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <label for="" class="form-check-label">
                          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                        </label>
                      </div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="table__task__text">
                    <span class="notebookLine1 "></span>
                    <span class="notebookLine2 "></span>
                    <span class="tdLine"></span>
                      Call Mam
                  </td>
                  <td class=" ml-auto" id="vis">
                      <img src="images/movearrow.png
                      " alt="movearrow">
                      <span class="utilites__lines1"></span>
                      <img src="images/pencil.png" alt="chengetext" >
                      <span class="utilites__lines2"></span>
                      <img src="images/trashbox.png" alt="deletetask">
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('tbody tr:not(.addPole)').hover(function(){
        $(this).children().css("visibility","visible")
    },
    function() {
        $(this).children().css("visibility","hidden")
    }
    );


});
```

Нужно что бы для каждой отдельной строки `tr` , появлялся скрытый `td` который находится в этой же строке.
А с этим кодом ,хоть и появляется скрытый `td` но как только свожу мышь с `tr` , `background` tr-a становится белым

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам разобрался можно сделать через псевдокласс

```css
tbody > tr > td.ml-auto {
    display:none;
}
tbody > tr:hover > td.ml-auto {
    display:block;
}
```